# Why can some classes and/or methods be called without instances of their parent class?

Tags: ruby, class

I'm near the finish of the Ruby track in Code Academy, and I'm curious about a peculiar thing: I was under the impression that a class is a repository of constants, methods, etc... and that in order to access most of them, you would first need to create an instance of that class or in some cases the methods of themselves can be invoked (as in they are all technically part of the global object). And then I saw something like this:

```
#Worked
Time.now
```

I understood as this as the method [now] of instance of class [Time] being invoked. I then tried to invoke the method on its own:

```
#Failed
now
```

and that failed, and I assumed that while a method can be created in the general scope [as part of the global object], if it relies on initialized variables of "parent" class, it cannot be called on its own, because it would not know which object to search for those initialized variables. Following that I created a test class:

```
class Clock
  def initialize
    @hours = 1
    @minutes = 30
  end

  def showTime
    puts "The time is: #{@hours}:#{@minutes}"
  end
end

#this worked
watch = Clock.new
watch.showTime

#this failed
showTime
```

I then just created a basic method (assuming it's in the global level)

```
def mymethod
    puts "The mighty METHOD!"
end

#Works
mymethod
```

and calling this method the way I did, without referencing the global object worked. So... the questions I have are as follows:

1. How can [Time.now] be called in this fashion? Shouldn't there be an instance of Time first created?
2. Why can't I call the method [now] on its own? Am I right that it relies on resources that it cannot find when called this way?
3. Why could I not call the method showTime on its own? But if I define any method on the "global" level I can access it without referencing the global object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your intuition is correct.

Every methods must be an instance method of some receiver.

**Global methods** are defined as private instance methods on `Object` class and hence seem to be globally available. Why? From any context `Object` is always in the class hierarchy of `self` and hence private methods on `Object` are always callable without receiver.

```
def fuuuuuuuuuuun
end

Object.private_methods.include?(:fuuuuuuuuuuun)
# => true
```

**Class methods** are defined as instance methods on the "singleton class" of their class instance. Every object in Ruby has two classes, a "singleton class" with instance methods just for that one single object and a "normal class" with method for all objects of that class. Classes are no different, they are objects of the `Class` class and may have singleton methods.

```
class A
  class << self # the singleton class
    def example
    end
  end
end

A.singleton_class.instance_methods.include?(:example)
# => true
```

Alternative ways of defining class methods are

```
class A
  def self.example
  end
end

# or 

def A.example
end
```

Fun fact, you can define singleton methods on any object (not just on class objects) using the same syntax `def (receiver).(method name)` as follows

```
str = "hello"

def str.square_size
  size * size
end

str.square_size
# => 25

"any other string".square_size
# => raises NoMethodError
```

---

*Some programming language history — Singleton classes are taken from the Smalltalk language where they are called "metaclasses". Basically all object-oriented features in Ruby (as well as the functional-style enumerators on `Enumerable`) are taken from the Smalltalk language. Smalltalk was an early class-based object-oriented language created in the 70ies. It was also the language that invented graphical user interfaces like overlapping windows and menus et cetera. If you love Ruby maybe also take a look at Smalltalk, you might fall in love yet again.*

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that "class method" is merely a shorthand term we Rubyists assign to a certain way of using instance methods (basically, because "instance method of the singleton class of an instance of the `Class` class" is a tongue-twister), and that they do not actually exist in the Ruby Language. While well-meaning, it is ultimately confusing for newbies, and complicates, rather than simplifies their understanding of the language. Why tell them there are multiple kinds of methods when in fact the reality is much simpler?

Comment: I am actually curious as to why Matz chose to introduce hidden singleton classes in Ruby rather than just going with Smalltalk's metaclasses? I find Smalltalk's class hierarchy easier to understand.

Comment: In Smalltalk, only classes have metaclasses (and metclasses don't). In Ruby, every object has a singleton class, including singleton classes. There's a whole lot more of them. I guess, it would swamp the output of reflective methods such as `class` and `ancestors`, if they weren't hidden. Think about it: *every* object's `class` pointer points to its singleton class. If they weren't hidden, then `Object#class` would always just return the singleton class, and thus would be pretty useless! The power of singleton classes over metaclasses is that *every* object can have individual methods.

Comment: Comparing Ruby to Java and Smalltalk: Ruby and Smalltalk have *one* kind of methods, Java has three (instance methods, static methods (which are really just procedures and not "methods" at all in the OO sense), and constructors (which are somewhat in between static methods and instance methods)). Conversely, Java has only one kind of class, whereas Smalltalk has two (classes and metaclasses) and Ruby has three (classes, singleton classes, and include classes).

Comment: Yay for nerding out about this!  Re swamped—as far as I understand Ruby objects have one "singleton class" only in their ancestry chain, expect for class objects which have a chain of "singleton classes" that mirrors the class hierarchy. // Re object methods in Smallralk—almost all dialects support changing the class pointer, so it is always possible to introduce a class for just one object. Fun fact, you can even point the class pointer to `self` (given the object has the correct structure) and thus create Self/Javascript style prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a class method. If CodeAcademy didn't cover it, that's a shame. Here's some examples:

```
# basic way
class Foo
  def self.bar; :ok; end
end
Foo.bar # => :ok

# alternate syntax
class Foo
  class << self
    def bar; :ok; end
  end
end

# alternate syntax, if Foo class already exists
def Foo.bar; :ok; end

# alternate approach if Foo class already exists
Foo.class_exec do
  def bar; :ok; end
end

# to define a class method on an anonymous 'class' for a single instance
# you won't need to use this often
Foo.new.singleton_class.class_exec do
  def bar; :ok; end
end

# to define a class method on an instance's actual class
Foo.new.class.class_exec do
  def bar; :ok; end
end
```

Another way to get class methods is to `extend` a module.

```
module FooMethods
  def bar; :ok; end
end
module Foo
  extend FooMethods
end
Foo.bar # => :ok
```

Note that with Modules, the methods are always defined as instance methods. This way they can be either `extended` into class scope or `included` into instance scope.  Modules can also have class methods, using the exact same syntax / examples as shown above with classes. However there's not such as easy to load a module's class methods via `include` or `extend`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Time.now`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-c-now) is a [class method](http://culttt.com/2015/06/10/understanding-class-methods-verses-instance-methods-in-ruby/).

To define a class method, you need to define the method with `self.`  : `def self.method_name`

```
class Clock
  @hours = 1
  @minutes = 30

  def self.showTime
    puts "The time is: #{@hours}:#{@minutes}"
  end
end

Clock.showTime
#=> The time is: 1:30
```

If you want to call `now` on its own, you can do so inside `Time` class :

```
class Time
  puts now
  #=> 2017-01-19 22:17:29 +0100
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can [Time.now] be called in this fashion? Shouldn't there be an
>   instance of Time first created?

The `Time.now` method is a class method, not an instance method and therefore can be called directly on the `Time` class rather than an instance of it `Time.new`

Class methods are defined on the class themselves using the `self` keyword:

```
class Time
  def self.now
    # code
  end
end

Time.now # works
```

> Why can't I call the method [now] on its own? Am I right that it
>   relies on resources that it cannot find when called this way?

When you call a method "on its own" you're actually implicitly calling it on self:

```
self.now
```

The above is the same as just doing:

```
now
```

> Why could I not call the method showTime on its own? But if I define
>   any method on the "global" level I can access it without referencing
>   the global object

You defined the `showTime` method on a specific class so you have to send that method to that class. When you define a method in the "global" scope you're implicitly defining it on `self` and the subsequent call to `mymethod` is actually `self.mymethod` so it will work.